# Alternative method for findPreference

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

What method should be called instead of `findPreference` since that method is deprecated? 
[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmlMQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's that the entire method of using `PreferenceActivity` to host preferences is deprecated. You should be using `PreferenceFragment`. See [`PreferenceActivity' docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity) for details.

> This is the base class for an activity to show a hierarchy of
>   preferences to the user. Prior to HONEYCOMB this class only allowed
>   the display of a single set of preference; this functionality should
>   now be found in the new PreferenceFragment class. If you are using
>   PreferenceActivity in its old mode, the documentation there applies to
>   the deprecated APIs here.